# Настройка умного фильтра Битрикс

Tags: битрикс, фильтр

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с "умным фильтром" на битрикс.

Я хочу установить на сайте фильтр только по одному параметру (Принт товара).
Каким образом я могу передать код/id нужного свойства торгового предложения в компонент catalog.smart.filter, чтобы мне не выводились все свойства торговых предложений, у которых стоит участие в умном поиске?
[image: Пример будущего расположения фильтра]

Comment: В настройках компонента умного фильтра уберите остальные свойства

Comment: К сожалению, этот вариант не подойдет, я буду вызывать еще один экземпляр catalog.smart.filter

Comment: Так вам нужен фильтр или сортировка? Задайте нормально вопрос. Если вы хотите добавить еще одну сортировку "синий блок куда ведет красная стрелка" это совсем другой вопрос

Comment: Вопрос уточню еще раз.
Слева находится умный фильтр по тем характеристикам(свойствам), по которым я хочу фильтровать товары.
Но мне требуется вызвать еще один экземпляр умного фильтра под слайдером, в котором было бы только одно свойство "Принт серии Simple" с выпадающим списком.
Вот и вопрос: как я могу под слайдером указать еще один умный фильтр только с "Принт серии Simple"?

Comment: При вызове нового экземпляра catalog.smart.filter я указал в массиве новый ключ:
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
   "bitrix:catalog.smart.filter",
   "prints_filter",
   array(
   .....
                        CODE_PROPERTY => array("CODE_PARAM", ),
....),
   false
  );